# I'm getting <Identifier> expected error

Tags: java

In one class, I have a method:

```
public void initalizeElements()
{
//does some stuff
}
```

So then in another class I try:

```
Molecules mol = new Molecules();

mol.initalizeElements();
```

and I get an error on the second line saying " expected".

I feel like this is really easy and I'm just glancing over something simple, but I still can't figure it out. And before someone says it, yes I looked at the hundreds of other questions that have the same question as I do. But none of them seemed to help me.

Full Code:

```
package mymolecules;
public class Molecules 
{
        public String[] elements = new String[35];
        private int lazyCounter = 0;

        public void initalizeElements()
        {
        elements[lazyCounter] = "H";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "He";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Li";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Be";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "B";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "C";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "N";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "O";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "F";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Ne";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Na";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Mg";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Al";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "Si";
        lazyCounter += 1;
        elements[lazyCounter] = "P";
        ....
        ....
        //on so on for the hole periodic table
        }
}
```

and

```
package mymolecules;
public class Parser 
{
    private String conString = "";
    private int conInt = 0;
    private int indexer = 0;

    private int lazyCounter = 0;

    private String sortList = "";
    private int sortCount = 0;

    Molecules mol = new Molecules();

    mol.initalizeElements();


    private String formula;
    public Parser(String Formula)
    {
        this.formula = Formula;
    }
    public void Sort()
    {
    while (lazyCounter > 34)
    {
        try {
        if (formula.contains(mol.elements[lazyCounter])) //Does the String contain the letter "H"
        {
            indexer = formula.indexOf(mol.elements[lazyCounter]); //indexer = where in the String "H" is located.
            if (formula.substring(indexer+1,indexer+2).matches("e")) //if "e" is located right after "H"
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Skip"); //Skipping because we'll deal with it later
                    }
            else
            {
               if (formula.substring(indexer+1,indexer+2).matches("[1-999].*")) // if any number is located after H
               {
                   conString = formula.substring(indexer+1,indexer+2); //Take the number after "H" and put it in conString
                   conInt = Integer.parseInt(conString); //conInt = ConString as an Integer
                   System.out.println("H"+conInt); //Print out "H" and the number
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println(mol.elements[lazyCounter]);
               }
            }   
        }
        }
        catch (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) //Catches the error from earlier
        {
            System.out.println("Whew caught an error!"); //rest of this is self explanitory.
            System.out.println(mol.elements[lazyCounter]);
        }
        lazyCounter += 1;
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: This snippet looks fine. Can you share some more context please?

Comment: is `mol.initalizeElements();` in a method?

Comment: @Mureinik sure 1 sec

Comment: @Mureink uploaded full code

Comment: @Reimeus uploaded full code for you to look at

Comment: @KiwiNinja look again at my previous comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Parser class you have this 2 lines

```
Molecules mol = new Molecules();
mol.initalizeElements();
```

outside of a method, this normally must happen in some constructor, move it inside of it...

it is a bad practice to init objects like that...

try something more elegant like:

```
public class Parser {
    private String conString = "";
    private int conInt = 0;
    private int indexer = 0;

    private int lazyCounter = 0;

    private String sortList = "";
    private int sortCount = 0;
    private Molecules mol;
    private String formula;

    public Parser(String Formula){
        this.formula = Formula;
        mol = new Molecules();
        mol.initalizeElements();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start calling methods in the section of the class used for defining variables. Move these to your constructor:

```
mol = new Molecules();
mol.initalizeElements();
```

Keep only the declaration of mol in the section for defining variables, where it goes:

```
private Molecules mol;
```

Answer (score 0):

On this level only field / method / constructor / class declarations / initializer blocks are allowed.

```
Molecules mol = new Molecules();
{
    mol.initalizeElements();
}
```

The above would be an initializer block. Its usage is mainly for filling a map. More usual would be to place the method call in the constructor.

```
public Parser(String Formula) {
    mol.initalizeElements();
}
```